# How to Find out the Best Way to Encode Data in ML?

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, data-visualization, data-mining

I have been thinking in this problem for quite a while, I cannot figure out a way of knowing, (based on the task) what will be the best data encoding I can do for training the model.

Imagine I have a variable `var` with the value:

```
var = "hello"
```

I can think of multiple ways of encoding this to feed a model, for example:

-- Tokenize letter by letter:

```
encoded = [22, 1, 18, 27, 28, 27, 29, 8, 5, 12, 12, 15, 29]
# tokenizer = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4, 'e': 5, 'f': 6, 'g': 7, 'h': 8, 'i': 9, 'j': 10, 'k': 11, 
   'l': 12, 'm': 13, 'n': 14, 'o': 15, 'p': 16, 'q': 17, 'r': 18, 's': 19, 't': 20, 'u': 21, 
   'v': 22, 'w': 23, 'x': 24, 'y': 25, 'z': 26, ' ':27, '=':28, '"':29}
```

-- Tokenize word by word:

```
encoded = [0, 1, 2]
# tokenizer = {'var':0, '=':1, '"hello"':2}
```

Or I could one hot encode, or use bag of words...
In the same way, having values:

```
values =  [1, 2, 3]
```

is essentialy the same as having:

```
values = [[1,0,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,1]]
```

or:

```
values = [0.0, 0.6931471805599453, 1.0986122886681098]
# [math.log(i) for i in [1, 2, 3]]
```

What I'm trying to show is that all those representations of the data have the same relationship between them, and, here is my question, an algorithm would be capable of understand its patterns using any of this encodings, right? How can I know what is the best suitable encoding for each task in ML? I suppose that this deppends on the model or on the data being used, but is there a method to know the best encoding of the data for each situation?

Answer (score 1):

There is no "best" way to encode your data before knowing what model you will use and its performances. You can optimize for memory or other constraint, but no definite answer can be given based like that.

However there is an entire field of NLP dedicated to word embedding. It basically encodes words (or tokens) into fixed-length real vectors. There are many ways to create embeddings but what they all try to do is to account for the pattern that in present in Natural Language regardless of the task you will try to solve later.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_embedding